# Swift 5.2 on Mojave

Tags: swift, macos, macos-mojave, swift5

I'm stuck with macOS Mojave (32 bits apps that can't be replaced) and I need to compile some code written in swift 5.2. It's not an iOS app, it's a command line app.

I know I can't use Xcode 11.4 to do it. But I would like to know if there's a way to install the `swift` command line. I mean may be the way it's done on linux, but I've seen nothing about it...

Any idea?

**EDIT**: Virtualization is not an option here.

Comment: You could try to run Catalina in a Virtual Box / Vmware Fusion / Parallels and use Xcode in it

Comment: Thank you for this idea but virtualization is not acceptable, thanks anyway, I'll edit my post to add this constraint.